# iphone Simulator crash?

Tags: iphone, crash, ios-simulator

I'm develop app for iPhone & iPod and during developing app i used simulator 3.2(iPad) it runs perfectly but when I want to my app on simulator 3.1.3 it generate one error I remove this error by comment this line   //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
and build project successfully but run app on simulator 3.1.3 when i clicking on button it goes on another screen on 3.2 simulator perfectly & crash on 3.1.3
what i do for come out from it.

Comment: Please check the method documentation before u use them, if they are available in your working sdk. As it is clearly written that clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear is available above 3.2. It will sort your most of the problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) clearly state that  `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` is available on iOS 3.2 and above. It crashes in 3.1.3 because this property does not exist in 3.1.3 (you can easily surmise this from reading the documentation for the property that you have already discovered is causing the issue, or from looking at the error message which will indicate that the object does not respond to a selector for `setClearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`.

Before setting this, you can check for this property and then set it, otherwise your older code can just be supported as is, or you could do something more advanced and add the property in pre-3.2 environments.

To check for the code, you do something like this:

```
if( [UITableViewController instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setClearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear:)] ) {
  // This is 3.2+ so we can use this property
  [self setClearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear:NO];
} else {
  // This is something earlier than 3.2, so we ignore it
  NSLog(@"will clear selection: pre-3.2");
}
```

Comment: where i put this code & when i put it into viewDidload method then its says warning class may not responde setClearsSelectorOnViewWillAppear method.plz explain in detail i'm newbe with it.

Comment: @suchita: I spelled the method wrong, which is why you got the warning. Please double-check code and don't just cut & paste. I will edit the answer, but it's up to you to ensure the quality of code you find online.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your question more clearly?

My dear friend,

You should read the Apple documentation more attentively,

It is clearly stated that

clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear

is a method available from iPhone OS 3.2 and later,you are trying to use it in 3.1.3.

So the result is obvious.

clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear
A Boolean value indicating if the controller clears the selection when the table appears.

@property(nonatomic) BOOL clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear

Discussion
The default value of this property is YES. When YES, the table view controller clears the table’s current selection when it receives a viewWillAppear: message. Setting this property to NO preserves the selection.

Availability
Available in iPhone OS 3.2 and later.
Declared In
UITableViewController.h

Thanks